# Javascript / Jquery multidimensional array

Tags: arrays, json, multidimensional-array, stringify

I Have an array like this :

```
var ProG = [[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]];
```

I have also a hidden field (id=prog-id) in a form, that I use to send this array to the server:

```
jQuery('#prog-id').val(JSON.stringify(ProG));
```

the sent array become:

```
"prog": "[[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]"
```

the next code take the array and other data from the server with ajax request:

value is the data that come from ajax
I create an object:

```
var obj  = jQuery.parseJSON(value);
```

Now the problem:
if I console.log(ProG) the array before sent I get:

```
Array[7]0: Array[4]1: Array[4]2: Array[4]3: Array[4]4: Array[4]5: Array[4]6: Array[4]length: 7__proto__: Array[0]
```

that is ok.

But If I do the same after getting array I receive this:

```
[[1,0,0,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

How can I put the received array in original format?

Comment: formatted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I find out:
jQuery.parseJSON(ProG).